# Treatment of ENV and BASH_ENV in bash running in bash and sh mode

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find a way to invoke a shell (I need to support bash and posix shell for a start) that makes sure some commands are executed at the beginning (`/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` or just about anything).

When I do the following:

```
echo "echo 'test'" > /tmp/file
BASH_ENV=/tmp/file ENV=/tmp/file sh
```

I get:

```
test
$
```

Which is fine. Checking `$SHELL` reveals that it is actually `bash` running in `sh` mode.

When I try the same for `bash`:

```
echo "echo 'test'" > /tmp/file
BASH_ENV=/tmp/file ENV=/tmp/file bash
```

I get:

```
$
```

I expected `ENV` to cause bash to run the commands from my file in `sh` mode and `BASH_ENV` to do the same in regular mode, but this does not happen.

---

The broader context is that I am trying to build a docker container in which one can invoke `bash` or `sh`, but the environment variables make sure that some initialization is performed in the shell at the beginning.

So the minimal `Dockerfile` that reproduces the problem is:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add bash

RUN echo "echo 'test'" >> /etc/profile
ENV ENV=/etc/profile
ENV BASH_ENV=/etc/profile
```

Again, after building, running with `docker run ... sh` works as expected, whereas `docker run ... bash` does not read `/etc/profile`.

---

Why is there such a difference? Does this behavior contradict the manual?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`BASH_ENV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fENV) is only used for non-interactive bash:

> **`BASH_ENV`**
>
> If this variable is set when Bash is invoked to execute a shell script, its value is expanded and used as the name of a startup file
>   to read before executing the script. See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoked-non_002dinteractively).

And:

> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute.

But that's not the case for `ENV` and [bash invoked as `sh`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoked-with-name-sh):

> When invoked as an interactive shell with the name `sh`, Bash looks
>   for the variable `ENV`, expands its value if it is defined, and uses
>   the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.

Nothing in the question contradicts any of this.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the manual then. So to put it in simple words, `ENV` works in interactive `sh`, whereas `BASH_ENV` in non-interactive `bash`...

Comment: @MichałTrybus pretty much. For your specific case, it might be better to use an `ENTRYPOINT` script which does the initialization, irrespective of wthether bash or sh or something else is called.